# dn't find a grammar element for class

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest, jersey

i have a jersey service and am trying to call it using xmlhttprequest

```
    @POST
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public SomeJsonClass myService(SomeClassName classObject) throws RuntimeException, IOException,
            InterruptedException {
//Some code to handle request
return jsonClassObject;
```

}

I am trying to call it in the following way:

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>jQuery</title>
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    </head>
<body>

<p>Click the button to demonstrate the prompt box.</p>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
function myFunction()
{

    var json=prompt("Enter JSON");
    alert("JSON: "+json);

                var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
                xhr.open("post","http://localhost:8080/otp/rest/validate-otp");
                xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type","application/json;charset=UTF-8");
                xhr.responseType = "json";
                xhr.send(JSON.stringify(json));
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

I am getting a "Couldn't find a grammar element for class" warning when i try to run this code. when i try sending the same json using a rest client, the service gives the correct response.

what may be the issue here?

Answer (score 0):

See if this article - RESTful services with jQuery and Java using JAX-RS and Jersey http://coenraets.org/blog/2011/12/restful-services-with-jquery-and-java-using-jax-rs-and-jersey/ is helpful to you.